# Handling Non-fatal Exception: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava3.HttpException - HTTP 504 Gateway Time-out in Android with Retrofit and RxJava3

Tags: java, android

I'm encountering a non-fatal exception while using Retrofit with RxJava3 in my Android application. The issue arises specifically when making network requests, resulting in a **`retrofit2.adapter.rxjava3.HttpException: HTTP 504 Gateway Time-out`** error. How can I effectively handle this HTTP 504 Gateway Time-out error to ensure a smoother user experience and potentially retry the failed request in Android?

```
public void notifyAnalyticsForBannerConfirmation(String bannerId, Boolean isDisplay, Boolean isClicked) {
        UserSavedLocation userLocationSelection = getPreviousLocationSelection();

        BannerCriteria bannerCriteria = new BannerCriteria();
        bannerCriteria.setBannerId(bannerId);
        bannerCriteria.setLatitude(userLocationSelection.getLocation().getPoint().get(1));
        bannerCriteria.setLongitude(userLocationSelection.getLocation().getPoint().get(0));
        bannerCriteria.setDisplay(isDisplay);
        bannerCriteria.setClicked(isClicked);
        bannerCriteria.setSessionId(CONST_USER_ANALYTICS_GUID);

        mAnalyticsBannerRepository.addBannerClick(bannerCriteria).retry((integer, throwable) -> throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                
            }
        });
    }
```

However, whenever the server response encounters a 504 Gateway Time-out, it triggers the onError method with the retrofit2.adapter.rxjava3.HttpException. How can I specifically catch and manage this exception to handle retries or implement a fallback mechanism for these timeout scenarios? Is there a way to handle this at the Retrofit level or within RxJava3?

Any insights, code examples, or best practices to gracefully handle this HTTP 504 error within the Retrofit and RxJava3 setup would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!